# Can a function detect the trigger event type?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am using a function in PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc() RETURNS trigger AS $$ ... $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mycheck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myfunc();
```

My problem now is to express  a condition about events in the body of that function like (pseudocode):

```
IF TRIGGER_EVENT_WAS_INSERT THEN ...doThis... END IF;
```

**How to express this condition?**
(Note `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` in the trigger!)

Comment: Hum... I am reading  [pgdoc about plpgsql-trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html): I will try the `TG_OP` *special variable*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, **`TG_OP`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> `TG_OP`
> Data type text; a string of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `TRUNCATE` telling for which operation the trigger was fired.

Careful what you *return* in each case. Sometimes you want to `RETURN NEW`, which is not defined in case of a `DELETE` or vice versa. If it gets too complex, rather split into multiple triggers, called on separate events.

Example:

```sql
IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
   -- do something
   RETURN OLD;  -- depends!
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN  
   -- do something
   RETURN NEW;  -- depends!
END IF;
```

[More code examples in related answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D++%5Btrigger%5D+code%3ATG_OP)