# What is PostgreSQL equivalent of INSERTING from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger that catches `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and based on the action performs something. In Oracle it can be done doing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ABC_BIU BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ABC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    ...
  END IF;

 ...
END;
```

[Here](http://psoug.org/definition/INSERTING.htm) is mentioned that `INSERTING` is a keyword used in conjunction with the `TRIGGER` in Oracle and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm) you can see the usage:

```
IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;
```

Comment: `TG_OP` see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need a separate **trigger function** in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_abc_biu()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$ 
BEGIN  
   CASE TG_OP           -- to fork depending on operation
   WHEN ' INSERT' THEN
      -- do something
   WHEN ' UPDATE' THEN
      -- do something
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'This trigger function expects INSERT or UPDATE!';
   END CASE;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... which can then be used in a **trigger** (or several):

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc_biu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON abc
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_abc_biu();
```

Related answer with more details:

- [Can a function detect the trigger event type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743766/can-a-function-detect-the-trigger-event-type/23744320#23744320)