# Best way to get Static data inside before trigger

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, plpgsql

I defined the below plpgsql function (Before trigger) to update the data if one of the column provided , I will get the other one from static data. But I want to know what is the best way to get the static data for given "columna", I need to get the "columnb" from static_tbl (more like dictionary / map datastrcuture). At the moment I am querying inside the Trigger function on the static table .

I know that i can use the case statement as well instead of querying . Please let me know what will be the best fit here.
Adding the test data 
**Say ColumnA contains 'a' it will be propagated to ColumnB as 'Alphabet A'
Otherwise ColumnB contains 'Alphabet A' it will be propagated to ColumnA as 'a' .** What is the best way to store the static data used for conversion columnA value to columnB value?

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_tblname_column_b () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN                                                                        
        IF NEW IS NULL THEN                                                               
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'this function cannot be installed with a DELETE trigger';
    END IF;
    IF NEW.column_b IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column_a IS NULL THEN
        NEW.column_a = (select column_a from static_tbl where column_b = NEW.column_b);
    ELSIF NEW.column_a IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column_b IS NULL THEN
        NEW.column_b = (select column_b from static_tbl where column_b = NEW.column_a);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER populate_column
                            BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON creatives FOR each ROW
                            EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tblname_column_b();
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please add the trigger itself not only the trigger function. please add sample data of what should be before and after the trigger.

Comment: @SMW Added the trigger definition itself and some test sample of the definition of trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `column_a` is functionally dependent on `column_b` (or vice versa) in a stable manner the *best way* is ***not*** to store the functionally dependent value at all. Look it up on the fly. Maybe create a view (or materialized view) for convenience. Possibly ensure referential integrity with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Incorporate the look-up in your input logic. Then you don't need a trigger.

If you actually need both columns and a trigger, fix a **sneaky bug**: You declare *variables* `column_a` and `column_b`, those are visible in the function body everywhere. When you use the identical *column* names `column_a` and `column_b` without table qualification you produce a **naming conflict**. Related:

- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105831/3684)

The solution in your case is simple: don't declare the variables to begin with, you have no use for them. The general solution is to *always* table-qualify column names if conflicts are possible. I implemented both:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_tblname_column_b()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN                                                                        
   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'This function cannot be used for  DELETE trigger.';
   END IF;

IF NEW.column_b IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column_a IS NULL THEN
   SELECT INTO NEW.column_a  s.column_a
   FROM   static_tbl s
   WHERE  s.column_b = NEW.column_b;

ELSIF NEW.column_a IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column_b IS NULL THEN
   SELECT INTO NEW.column_b  s.column_b
   FROM   static_tbl s
   WHERE  s.column_a = NEW.column_a;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also, don't check for NULL to identify the trigger type, this can be corner-case incorrect. Check the special variable `TG_OP` instead:

- [Can a function detect the trigger event type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743766/can-a-function-detect-the-trigger-event-type/23744320#23744320)

---

An alternative way to store lookup values would be the [**`enum`** data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html). But I wouldn't use `enum` for more than a couple of options and only if they hardly ever change. Actually, I prefer lookup tables with FK constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 1) I don't need the column_a, column_b declaration , I removed the same from my question 2) Why I can't  use Trigger ? (Ans: Yes you are correct we can use Views as mentioned but in future,I am going to retain column_b (which is new column) and deprecate/drop column_a (old column) ) 3) My real question is there any other way to store the look-up data (similar to dictionary in python) . Because I just want to know is there better ways to store the look up data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method of creating a dictionary using a table structure like that would work, though the else clause doesn't quite make sense to me. Did you mean "WHERE column_a = NEW.column_a"? Anyway, this might be slightly simpler:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_tblname_column_b () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE 
        column_a tblname.column_a%TYPE;
        column_b tblname.column_b%TYPE;
    BEGIN                                                                        
        IF NEW IS NULL THEN                                                               
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'this function cannot be installed with a DELETE trigger';
    END IF;

    NEW.column_a = COALESCE(NEW.column_a, (SELECT column_a FROM static_tbl WHERE column_b = NEW.column_b));
    NEW.column_b = COALESCE(NEW.column_b, (SELECT column_b FROM static_tbl WHERE column_a = NEW.column_a));

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER populate_column
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON creatives FOR each ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tblname_column_b();
```

The COALESCE function returns the first non-null argument in its list. If all arguments are NULL, then it returns NULL.

Depending on how you intend to use this, you might be better off using some of the new JSON capabilities in postgres 9.3 and later. That would give you another way of creating key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for simplification suggestion provided :-) Could you give me any reference for how to create dict like structures in Postgres and use the same in PlPgsql function  ?

Comment: There are at least a couple of options for using key/value pairs in postgres. One is via hstore: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/    Another via json:  http://stormatics.com/howto-use-json-functionality-in-postgresql/

Comment: @Shankar: This trigger function would produce an error `column reference "column_a" is ambiguous` due to the (needless) naming conflict. Just like the original. This answer is actually inferior to the original, running SELECTs unconditionally, which is a waste.